# Send mail in Laravel with Hostgator

Tags: laravel, email

what shoud be the .env and mail.php set up to send mail in laravel using hostgator
this is my **.env**

```
     MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
     MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
     MAIL_PORT=587
     MAIL_USERNAME=userid 
     MAIL_PASSWORD=password
     MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

FROM adrress is info@domain.com.My domain is SSL certified but still I got blank screen with error 500 sending it.

Comment: We need an error message to present a solution. What does "having trouble" mean?

Comment: I am getting error 500 . But the code was working well on local environment .

Answer (score 1):

No need to **change** in **mail.php** file

i have tried with **sendGrid** *successfully* . Refer this:

> https://github.com/YasinPatel/send-email-in-laravel-using-sendgrid